# If contract started on 13th and there is a probation period of one month, when does probation end?

Tags: contracts, performance-reviews, probation

If my first day of work is on the 13th and my contract says there is "one month" probation period, how many days is that? There are no specific dates. It only says "one month".

Is it 30 days? 31 days? Will it be on the 13th of the next month? I presume it ends on the 13th of the following month?

Comment: Ask the company and check against any pertinent laws or regulations in your jurisdiction.

Comment: indeed, ask if you want to know exactly to the day. But why does it even matter? Unless you get told you didn't pass just on the edge of the interval, it's irrelevant. And if that's what's happening, you won't have a long future in the company even if you did by contract law last until after the interval was over.

Comment: @jwenting Careful asking why it matters. That seems to really set off the OP.

Comment: I will say if it starts on the 13th of one month then it will end on the 13th of the second month. In most of the companies, it works like this it doesn't matter that month has 30 days/31 days/28 days. It also doesn't matter that between 2 months it covers 30 days or 31 days.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie all the more reason to push his nose into it, some self reflection may be in order :)

Comment: Can you please add a country tag? In Germany, the meaning of "one month" in contracts is regulated by law.

Answer (score 4):

Since "a month" is not a specified number of days (it's somewhere between 28 and 31), I would assume "one month from now" is the same day in the next month. So in your case the 13th of the next month should be the end of your probation, in a normal person's understanding.

However, legally, this probably is a minefield with many, many variables. If you are asking for legal reasons and not out of pure curiosity, you need to hire a local lawyer specialized in labor/employment law in your juristiction.

Comment: Or ask to improve that part of the contract (if not signed yet) by using more precise language.

Comment: @Roland If an employee was asking for a change to the contract to be more precise with regards to probation, I would probably just dismiss them. They sound like such a hassle to work with.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie That's fine. I wouldn't want to work for an employer who doesn't give me a contract with unambiguous language anyway.

Comment: @Roland Sure. For things that matter. 28 vs 31 days probation does not matter.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie If we knew that it doesn't matter, we wouldn't need a probation period. The contract (and the law) are all that matters. Ambiguous contracts are one reason why lawyers have a steady income.

Comment: @Roland All contracts are ambiguous to a degree. It just comes down to how pedantic you want to be with the terms. In addition, the law often has grey areas. Someone that looks like they will only act absolutly according to precise terms in the contract would be a pain to work with.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie That's fine. I value the security of precise regulations in my employment contract. I prefer to know my rights and duties. If you find that a pain to work with, you don't need to hire me. Btw., I live in a country where OP's question is answered by the [law](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__188.html). So, I wouldn't bother anybody with this.